# SQL Server Express 10 gb limitation workaround using multiple schema

Tags: sql-server-express

We are developing an intranet web application for our organization via third party vendor and the vendor who is implementing this for us has provided SQL Server Express edition. As we know, SQL Server Express has a limitation of 10 gb only so we have asked the vendor to provide SQL Server Standard or other paid licensed db with no size limitation.

But the vendor is saying that they have implemented system in such a way that automatically new schema is created by system periodically such that 10 gb limitation will not impact system. As per vendor multiple schema are automatically used by application as required with no manual intervention. So according to vendor 10 gb limitation is not a problem.

But we are not satisfied with vendor reply.

Comment: The 10 gb limit is **per file** - adding a second schema in the same database **DOES NOT** solve this "issue" and does **NOT** get around this limitation. The only way to get around this is by splitting up into **multiple databases** so each is in their own file and gets 10gb each

Comment: There is always Developer Edition which is free, not that I would be the one to tell you to break licencing regs... And Web Edition isn't so badly priced

Comment: @marc_s Really appreciate your inputs . Few more queries in this regard .Is  splitting into multiple db recommended for enterprise usage, any usage terms violation if splitting is implemented ? I mean if my vendor proposes this splitting solution should we accept this as we are paying vendor but looks like vendor is trying to cut their cost by giving us limited features.

Comment: For enterprise usage - **license** a *real* edition - fiddling around with multiple 10gb database files is **AT BEST** a temporary hack and kludgy workaround - but **NOT** something I'd recommend AT ALL

Comment: @marc_s  Thank you very much for your time and inputs ! We will ask for real licensed edition